# JS dispatchEvent not working

Tags: javascript, google-search-console

Usually i don't put this kind of so specific question in SO, but i'm struggling with this issue for days, so i'm seeking for some help here.

I'm building an app to automate a task in web version of Whatsapp (https://web.whatsapp.com/). My goal is to click on a button on the interface to show some options, and then click on the same button again to hide it.

To simulate what i want to do manually :

1 - Open Whatsapp Web.

2 - Click on the 'Attach' button on the upper right corner of the interface, as shown in the image below.

[image]

3 - The attach options will show, as the image below :

[image]

4 - Click on the 'Attach' button again, and the attach options will hide.

That's it, but i want do this programatically using Javascript (pure JS, no JQuery).

To achieve the task in step 2, i'm using the code below with success :

```
var nodes = document.getElementsByTagName('span');
if (typeof lastElementId == 'undefined')
    var lastElementId = 0;
var result = undefined;
for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
    var h = nodes[i].outerHTML;
    var flag = false;
    flag = (h.toLowerCase().indexOf('data-icon="clip') > -1);
    if (flag) {
        result = h;
        lastElementId = i;
        break;
    }
}
if (result !== undefined) {
    function triggerMouseEvent(node, eventType) {
        var clickEvent = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
        clickEvent.initEvent(eventType, true, true);
        node.dispatchEvent(clickEvent);
    }
    triggerMouseEvent(nodes[i], "mouseover");
    triggerMouseEvent(nodes[i], "mousedown");
} else {
    console.log('Not found');
}
;
```

The code above will work to do the step 2, but won't work to do step 4. Manually when i click in the Attach button after the options are show, the options will hide. But not using my JS code.

What am i missing here ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**To fix the closing problem:**

1. Right click on the attach element.
2. Select `inspect element` in chrome browser
3. In the right panel select `Event Listeners` tab and find `mousedown` section
   [image]
4. Click the handler code and detect that we need to pass specific `screenX` and `screenY` to satisfy this particular business logic and pass through to `n.uie.requestDismiss()` part which apparently does what is says.
   [image]

So now we have enough information to try a possible solution, which apparently works for now. Goes like this:

```
const toggleAttach = () => {
  // select the span with reliable identification like data-*
  const clipNode = document.querySelector('[data-icon="clip"]');
  // take its element, i.e. the button itself
  const clipButtonNode = clipNode.parentNode;
  // extract the current offset position relative to the document
  // more info here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect
  // we can use this for filling in the non-0 screenX and screenY
  const clipButtonNodeClientRect = clipButtonNode.getBoundingClientRect();

  clipButtonNode.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent("mousedown", {
    bubbles: true,
    cancelable: true,
    screenX: clipButtonNodeClientRect.x,
    screenY: clipButtonNodeClientRect.y
  }));
}
```

**Now to understanding why the first mousedown works for opening:**

This is much harder to reverse engineer, but what I managed to find is if you install React DevTools (since whatsapp web is written in React) extension and open its tab in DevTools you will see:

[image]

And there you will find:

[image]

So we can make a very vague conclusion that opening and closing is handled in separate functions. Rest is up to you to figure out.

Hope this helped.

Comment: @delphirules welcome, I updated with additional info on how to check the opening part. Hope it helps. Cheers.